# Silent the zgrep results on *.gz files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

I need to silent the results(from zgrep) from getting displayed on the terminal. But when I use **-q** option on zgrep like this:

```
zgrep -q file.gz
```

then zgrep doesn't work.

From the man page of zgrep I was thinking that -q should have worked:

```
SYNOPSIS
       zgrep [ grep_options ] [ -e ] pattern filename...

DESCRIPTION
       Zgrep  invokes  grep  on  compressed or gzipped files.  All options specified are passed directly to grep.
```

Comment: You left off the `pattern` argument in that `zgrep -q file.gz` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the inbuilt return code `$?` to determine the output. You can also use `-q` or `--silent` or `--quiet`

```
spoof> zgrep -q existing file.txt.gz
spoof> echo $?
0
spoof> zgrep -q non_existing file.txt.gz
spoof> echo $?
1
```